# Putting MYSQL results into a PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array, using this structure.

```
$data = array(
array("firstname" => "Mary", "lastname" => "Johnson", "age" => 25),
array("firstname" => "Amanda", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 18)
);
```

I want to read data from a MYSQL table into this array. Here is my code

```
$sql = "select * from mynames limit 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
```

The array is not filling up. Can anybody show me how to fill the array?

Comment: Look in the [manual](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array).

Answer (score 14):

```
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $row[] = $data;
    }
    print_r($row);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to append results to `$data`? If so, you can do something like this:

```
$data = array(
    array("firstname" => "Mary", "lastname" => "Johnson", "age" => 25),
    array("firstname" => "Amanda", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 18)
);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mynames LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) !== false) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Or, if you're looking to merge the rows you get back from MySQL with the rows in `$data`, you can do something like:

```
$i = 0;
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) !== false) {
    $data[$i] = array_merge($data[$i], $row); 
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` will get the next row from the results, returning `false` when there are no more rows.  To propagate an array with all the results you need to iterate (e.g. with a `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array(...`).